# crt1.o error in mips cross compiler

Tags: linux, gcc, mips, cross-compiling, crt

I would like to generate MIPS binaries using gcc on an x86 machine. In order to install MIPS cross-compiler I followed the directions on [this page](http://www.linux-mips.org/wiki/Toolchains). I could install gcc and binutils successfully. I tried to to compile a simple hello world program using the cross compiler.

```
/opt/cross/bin/mipsel-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc -mips1 hi.c
```

I got the following error.

```
/opt/cross/lib/gcc/mipsel-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2/../../../../mipsel-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
/opt/cross/lib/gcc/mipsel-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2/../../../../mipsel-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
/opt/cross/lib/gcc/mipsel-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2/../../../../mipsel-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
/opt/cross/lib/gcc/mipsel-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2/../../../../mipsel-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find crtn.o: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I did some research online to figure out what the problem was, and changed the command I used to the following.

```
/opt/cross/bin/mipsel-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc -B/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -mips1 hi.c
```

Now I get this error message:

```
/opt/cross/lib/gcc/mipsel-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2/../../../../mipsel-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 3)
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o: error adding symbols: File in wrong format
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am not sure what the problem is. The only thing I can think of is the "--without-headers" option passed to configure program when building gcc. Configure command for gcc given on the linux-mips page is as below.

```
% ../gcc-3.8.2/configure --target=$TARGET --prefix=$PREFIX \
  --enable-languages=c --without-headers \
  --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as \
  --disable-shared --disable-threads \
  --disable-libmudflap --disable-libgomp \
  --disable-libssp --disable-libquadmath \
  --disable-libatomic
```

I would appreciate some help. The system on which I generated the cross compiler uses gcc4.7.2-5. I used the sources for gcc-4.8.2 and binutils-2.24 to generate the cross compiler.

Comment: If you just want to cross compile for mips-linux, you might want to look at http://ellcc.org. Binaries are available for download also.

Comment: You're missing a run-time library. A full development environment needs libraries built for the MIPS in addition to the compiler and binutils.

Answer (score 3):

> /opt/cross/bin/mipsel-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc -mips1 hi.c

Add a `SYSROOT` to the compile command. It should look similar to:

```
/opt/cross/bin/mipsel-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc -mips1 --sysroot=/opt/cross/... hi.c
```

The `SYSROOT` will provide the header and library path automatically (rather than adding `-I` and `-L` individually).

You will know when you have a `SYSROOT` because there will be a `bin/`, `include/` and `lib/` in the path used. For example, here's a `SYSROOT` for `arm-linux-gnueabi` (i.e., `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` and `arm-linux-gnueabi-g++`):

```
$ ls /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi
bin  include  lib
```

So, in this example, you would use `--sysroot=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi`.

If you need help with locating a `SYSROOT`, then perform a `find`:

```
$ find /usr -name crt1.o
/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/crt1.o
/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o
```

In your case, you would probably search from `/opt/cross`. Obviously, you would want the one for the target (`arm-linux-gnueabi`), and not the ones for the host (`x86_64-linux-gnu`).

Comment: When I use sysroot option I get the following error.
`/opt/cross/lib/gcc/mipsel-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2/../../../../mipsel-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: this linker was not configured to use sysroots`
I guess I have to recompile the whole thing with sysroot option.

Comment: Sorry puck, I've never seen that. But I don't build my own toolchains.

Answer (score 0):

Adding --sysroot= would resolve this issue.
As you are cross-compiling you shouldn't select just any other folder which has crt1.o or crtX.o as your sysroot directory. It could be your host-machine's files. (Which if you are running on a x86, it would be for x86). Again it varies from 32bit and 64bit.

With newer version's of GCC toolchain, you need to have a sdk part of it which has the appropriate sysroot and crt1.o. This should go with your ABI and your target architecture.